# AWS Lambda- Cannot find module 'csvtojson'

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, csvtojson

I am using AWS Lambda service to read the content from the CSV file uploaded on the S3 bucket and convert it to the JSON format. I got stuckup on the CSV to JSON phase.

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
    const S3 = new AWS.S3();

    exports.handler = async (event,content,callback) => {
        console.log(' inside trigger ')
        const src_bkt = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        const src_key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
        
        try {
            const params = {Bucket: src_bkt, Key:src_key}
       
       // get csv file and create stream
            const stream = S3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
            // convert csv file (stream) to JSON format data
            const json = await csvtojson().fromStream(stream);
            console.log(json);
      }
      catch (err) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        return {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
          body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message)
        }
      }
    };
```

**Error Message:**
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'csvtojson'",

I tried to convert the node module on the lambda to check any luck.

Comment: did you attach the node modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package and deploy the lambda as a zip file. The file should contain the javascript file with the handler function as well as the `node_modules` directory with all the dependencies.

#### Zip File structure.

handler.js

node_modules/

......................../csvtojson

#### how to setup the project

- initialise a project folder for e.g `my-project` using `npm init`, it will create a package.json file for you
- create the handler function in `handler.js`
- install csv2json using `npm install csv2json --save`, now you will see a `node_modules` directory created
- zip the `my-project` directory, so you have my-project.zip, the zip should directly contain the `handler.js` and `node_modules`

Reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-nodejs/

hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you know these things already. I felt like you created the lambda from AWS console directly without uploading zip file. Was I right

Comment: Yes, Arun. I am not aware of this. As you said, I directly created the Lambda on the AWS console.

Comment: Glad to be of help